# Objective-C: How to add thumbanils to a TableView From Videos?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Bellow i have some code that reads and lists the names of files in the documents directory of my application. This works fine and i know want to add thumnails from each of the videos i get so i found this code:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@""];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
cell.imageView.image = thumbnail;
[player stop];
```

However I'm not sure where to point the path to my files so that it adds a different thumbnail for every separate video my tableview is displaying.

Here is my full code where I'm getting the video files and displaying in table:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }


    NSLog(@"urlstring %@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];


    cell.textLabel.text = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
    filePathsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]mutableCopy]];

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@""];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    cell.imageView.image = thumbnail;
    [player stop];
    return cell;


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Instead, you should do the thumbnail generation when the controller is loaded and save the images into an `NSArray` / `NSCache` / disk with appropriate names. Then when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called you just get the appropriate image.

The code you have is close, you just want to loop over the file names in `filePathsArray` and actually create the `videoURL` from them.

Depending on how many there are you might also want to run this process on a background thread and just tell the table view to refresh as each one is loaded.